# javascript using filter w && not returning desired console.log

Tags: javascript, function, filter

/* I am essentially trying to use the && operator to return not only 20 and 40 from my array but also 30. I'm sure its a very simple error but I would love to know where I am bungling my syntax! Please excuse the bad semantics, I was repeating the same filter operation with variations for practice */

```
var numbersArray = [20, 25, 30, 40];

var filtering = numbersArray.filter(function resultNewNumbers(newnewNUM){
    return (newnewNUM % 20 === 0) && (newnewNUM % 10 === 0);
});

console.log(filtering);
```

Comment: It seems you just need `return (newnewNUM % 10 === 0);`.

Comment: Why not just use % 10, why have the %20 in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this test

```
(newnewNUM % 20 === 0) && (newnewNUM % 10 === 0)
```

you check if newnewNUM is a multiple of 20 **and** 10. Hence 30 is not a multiple of 30.

But if you modify your test this way:

```
(newnewNUM % 20 === 0) || (newnewNUM % 10 === 0) 30 will emerge
```

Comment: THis is why I asked.... because I needed another set of eyes to see the most basic of flaws. Embarrassed but THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This i.e `30 % 20 = 0.5`

```
var numbersArray = [20, 25, 30, 40];

var filtering = numbersArray.filter(function resultNewNumbers(newnewNUM){
    return (newnewNUM % 20 === 0) || (newnewNUM % 10 === 0);
});

console.log(filtering);
```

Or If you want to use the && Try below

```
var numbersArray = [20, 25, 30, 40];

var filtering = numbersArray.filter(function resultNewNumbers(newnewNUM){
    return (newnewNUM / 20 > 0) && (newnewNUM % 10 === 0);
});

console.log(filtering);
```